# Flyway with GitHub

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, flyway

I'm trying to use Flyway with GitHub Action. Are there any sample workflows around that? I am new to this area and looking for some samples to get started.

Answer (score 0):

There are examples on the Flywaydb.org website.

Here is the [self-hosted example](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/github-yml-self-hosted-agent-using-github-actions-188650704.html). This is the [container example](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/github-dockerized-yml-pipeline-using-github-actions-188645384.html). Walks through pretty much everything all the fundamentals to getting Flyway deployed using Github Actions.

Comment: Thanks! Checked this earlier. It didn't include the commands or provide template to run commands. Will need to use my own.